# perl to loop and check across files

Tags: perl

still having trouble with perl programming and I need to be pushed to make a script work out.
I have two files and I want to use the list file to "extract" rows from the data one. The problem is that the list file is formatted as follow:

```
X1 A B
X2 C D
X3 E F
```

And my data looks like this:

```
A X1 2 5
B X1 3 7
C X2 1 4
D X2 1 5
```

I need to obtain the element pairs from the list file by which select the row in the data file. At the same time I would like to write an output like this:

```
X1 A B 2 5 3 7
X2 C D 1 4 1 5
```

I'm trying writing a perl code, but I'm not able to produce something useful. I'm at this point:

```
open (LIST, "< $fils_list") || die "impossibile open the list";
@list = <LIST>;
close (LIST);
open (HAN, "< $data") || die "Impossible open data";
@r = <HAN>;
close (HAN);
for ($p=0; $p<=$#list; $p++){
chomp ($list[$p]);
($x, $id1, $id2) = split (/\t/, $list[$p]);
$pair_one = $id1."\t".$x;
$pair_two = $id2."\t".$x;

for ($i=0; $i<=$#r; $i++){
chomp ($r[$i]);
($a, $b, $value1, $value2) = split (/\t/, $r[$i]);
$bench = $a."\t".$b;

if (($pair_one eq $bench) || ($pair_two eq $bench)){
print "I don't know what does this script must print!\n";
}
}
}
```

I'm not able to rationalize about what to print.
Any kind of suggestion is very welcome!

Comment: Do you want merge 2 files keeping x1, X2 as keys ? do you want visualize your data as x1 = [A, B, 2, 5, 3, 7] likewise ?

Comment: @forvaidya I want to use the pairs derived from the "list_file" to extract row from the data.

Comment: @forvaidya not the visualization that you are saying, but the one that I wrote in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few general recommendations:

- Indent your code to show the structure of your program.
- Use meaningful variable names, not `$a` or `$value1` (if I do so below, this is due to my lack of domain knowledge).
- Use data structures that suit your program.
- Don't do operations like parsing a line more that once.
- In Perl, every program should `use strict; use warnings;`.
- `use autodie` for automatic error handling.

Also, use the `open` function like `open my $fh, "<", $filename` as this is safer.

Remember what I said about data structures? In the second file, you have entries like

```
A X1 2 5
```

This looks like a secondary key, a primary key, and some data columns. Key-value relationships are best expressed through a hash table.

```
use strict; use warnings; use autodie;
use feature 'say'; # available since 5.010

open my $data_fh, "<", $data;
my %data;
while (<$data_fh>) {
  chomp; # remove newlines
  my ($id2, $id1, @data) = split /\t/;
  $data{$id1}{$id2} = \@data;
}
```

Now `%data` is a nested hash which we can use for easy lookups:

```
open my $list_fh, "<", $fils_list;
LINE: while(<$list_fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($id1, @id2s) = split /\t/;
  my $data_id1 = $data{$id1};
  defined $data_id1 or next LINE;  # maybe there isn't anything here. Then skip

  my @values = map @{ $data_id1->{$_} }, @id2s;  # map the 2nd level ids to their values and flatten the list

  # now print everything out:
  say join "\t", $id1, @id2s, @values;
}
```

The `map` function is a bit like a foreach loop, and builds a list of values. We need the `@{ ... }` here because the data structure doesn't hold arrays, but references to arrays. The `@{ ... }` is a *dereference operator*.

Comment: Wow!....very clear and absolutely useful explanation. Thank you so much! I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it, mostly using Hashes resp. Hash- and Array-References (test1.txt and test2.txt contain the data you provided in your example):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $f1, '<','test1.txt') or die "Cannot open file1: $!\n";
open(my $f2, '<','test2.txt') or die "Cannot open file2: $!\n";

my @data1 = <$f1>;
my @data2 = <$f2>;

close($f1);
close($f2);

chomp @data1;
chomp @data2;

my %result;

foreach my $line1 (@data1) {
    my @fields1 = split(' ',$line1);
    $result{$fields1[0]}->{$fields1[1]} = [];
    $result{$fields1[0]}->{$fields1[2]} = [];
}

foreach my $line2 (@data2){
    my @fields2 = split(' ',$line2);
    push @{$result{$fields2[1]}->{$fields2[0]}}, $fields2[2];
    push @{$result{$fields2[1]}->{$fields2[0]}}, $fields2[3];
}

foreach my $res (sort keys %result){
    foreach (sort keys %{$result{$res}}){
        print $res . " " . $_ . " " .  join (" ", sort @{$result{$res}->{$_}}) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, your solution works fine for me. Anyway I got amon's one for the comprehensive explanation that I received. Thank you so much anyway!